# jQuery: get div-width after document is ready and rendered

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the width of a div container to set another css attribute in another div  to the width of the first one, which I know after the page was fully loaded and rendered.

I have this code:

```
$().ready(function() {
    doLayout();
}
function doLayout() {
    var $width = $("#sidebar").attr("width");
    $("#content").css("left", width);
}
```

The problem is, the ready is called before the page is rendered and thus width attribute is not set (or "undefined"). How can I determine the current width?

**EDIT:**
After suggested changes I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jMgfT/5/) but the code there is working, but in my real application it's not. So the problem is somewhere else, I guess :(

Comment: you forgot `document` keyword. `That's $(document).ready(function...)`

Comment: @aschuler. Check the API. you're wrong. though it's deprecated.

Comment: Could you provide a source ? If i read http://api.jquery.com/ready/ I see `$().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)`

Comment: @aschuler. Are you serious??? This is the source, It works but not recommended...

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood your reply.

Comment: Wow please look at http://api.jquery.com/ready/ Clearly states $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)

Comment: @Izdt. $().ready is called when everything is rendered...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) to wait for all images/external content to load as well, as these could alter element dimensions:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    doLayout();
});
```

Then to get the computed width, use [`width`](http://api.jquery.com/width/):

```
$("#content").width(); // width in px
```

Comment: the use of load may cause visible rendering issues may want to use a combiniation of both depending on what this is doing

Comment: thanks, have a working fiddle now (see EDIT in post) but my real code is still not.

Answer (score 2):

A `div` will have no attribute of `width`. It may have a CSS style property of `width`, which you can retrieve using [`.css('width')`](http://api.jquery.com/css), but you may also be interested in [`outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth) or [`innerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth) or [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width) which return the width computed by JavaScript.

```
$().ready(function() {
    doLayout();
}
function doLayout() {
    var $width = $("#sidebar").css("width");
    $("#content").css("left", width);
}
```

A good explanation of how the above mentioned `width` methods differ can be read in the documentation, but simply;

1. `outerWidth()` takes into account padding + margin
2. `width()` takes padding into account
3. `innerWidth()` takes neither into account.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    doLayout();
}


function doLayout() {
        var width = $("#sidebar").css("width");
        $("#content").css("left", width);
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to know css attribute width, since its not set and hte width is dynamic. I want to know actual rendered size in the browser window.

Comment: than you want to use .css("width") or outerWidth() or innerWidth() you also may need to wait til the load event fires. At the end of the day we do not have much info to go on you may want to post relevant code in a JS fiddle to show us and we can explain better how to solve your problem.

Comment: I've added working fiddle in my original question. How can I "wait" till load event fires? (sorry if its stupid question, I'm new to this).

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue (`offsetWidth` was 0 because element was not yet rendered). I did a simple:

```
setTimeout(function() {
 ... do stuff that needed final width of object ...
}, 0)
```

And it seems to work flawlessly on my case. This basically asks for being called back whenever javascript current callstack is empty.

I guess that if you create a DOM element in javascript and its width is defined in external CSS to be "100%", the `offsetWidth` (and `offsetHeight`) of this object won't get calculated before all javascript has finished running.

By using `setTimeout(callback, 0)`, it seems to be called after the browser finishes the javascript current call AND has taken the time to apply all CSS to new DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    doLayout();
}

function doLayout() {
    var width = $("#sidebar").css("width");
    $("#content").css("left", width);
}
```

This won't help you if the width is controlled by an image, as the images may not be rendered when the document is ready. If this still doesn't work, we need more context.

Comment: I think using .css('width') would be a better choice as well

Comment: What is the problem you fixed? I don't see any difference.

Comment: Thereis no difference as far as I understandit between $().someFunction(...) and $(document).someFunction(...). Both variants will get called in my code but my width is still "undefined".

Comment: I added the word 'document', which specifies that you are waiting for the document to be ready, which is the recommended use of ready() in this context.