# Remove icon when div is sized down to a certain width (bootstrap)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The code I am using is like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-5x"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                    <div class="huge">6</div>
                    <div>Maintenance</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="/maintenance.php">
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <span class="pull-left">View Tasks</span>
                <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, when the window is resized the fontawesome/glyphicon is too big. How can I make it such that if the div reaches a certain minimum width, the `fa-tasks` icon won't appear?

See this below, I'd prefer for the left example if it gets any smaller than that width that it just says "6 Maintenance" *without* the icon. Obviously the one on the right is fine, and how it should ordinarily look.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: give a new custom class to the glyph and change the font size. removing it will create an emptyness in the structure. reducing it will help.

Comment: I think you need to use javascript for that particular div. Measure the size of the div and depending on that you can apply classes for the elements.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) are the docs for bootstrap. Look at the hidden-xs class. This might help, but it does depend on the specifics of the html page, which was not posted.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the [Responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) like `hidden-sm` (in Bootstrap 3):

```
<i class="fa fa-tasks fa-5x hidden-sm"></i>
```

Comment: I had a look at the `hidden-xx` classes and have actually used them elsewhere - but in this case I don't think I can just rely on that, I'd prefer to hard code it such that when the outer div is diminished to a certain width, then I hide the icon. Can I do that?

Comment: I think that's what the `hidden-xx` classes are for.  Did you try it out?

Comment: I did try it. That's why I was hoping maybe I could just specify a minimum pixel width explicitly rather than relying on whatever sm/md/lg values Bootstrap uses?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the built-in Responsive utilities, you can add a custom [CSS media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries):

```
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .fa-tasks {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
```

This will cause the "fa-tasks" icon to disappear at screen widths below 600px.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I might have worded my question poorly. I'm not talking about the screen width, I'm talking about the div width. ie. that blue box with all the content in it. Because I find as I resize the screen, at certain points the div becomes too narrow for everything to fit. But even on mobile phone sized screens, it looks okay (because all the boxes go to new lines each). But at certain screen sizes in between, that's when the div width becomes too small. I hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a third option for you: [jQuery: get div-width after document is ready and rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9911554/584846).  Add two new classes, `task` and `task-icon` and some Javascript:

```
...
            <div class="row task">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-5x task-icon"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                <div class="huge">6</div>
                <div>Maintenance</div>
            </div>
        </div>
...
<script>
$().ready(function() {
    var $width = $(".task").attr("width");
    if ($width < 50)
        $(".task-icon").hide();
}
</script>
```